# Swagger code generator error with a reusable parameter

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, swagger-codegen

I have a following swagger file (parses fine with the Swagger online editor):

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: Sample
  version: 1.1.0

basePath: /base

paths:
  /sample:
    get:
      summary: Gets the samples
      parameters:
        - $ref: '#parameters/reusableParam'
      responses:
        200:
          description: Success
parameters:
  reusableParam:
    in: header
    name: sample-param
    required: true
    type: string
    description: Sample reusable parameter
```

When I run code generator on it:

```
java -jar swagger-codegen-cli-2.2.1.jar generate -i swagger.yaml -l java
```

It fails with an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at io.swagger.codegen.DefaultGenerator.generateParameterId(DefaultGenerator.java:803)
        at io.swagger.codegen.DefaultGenerator.processOperation(DefaultGenerator.java:727)
        at io.swagger.codegen.DefaultGenerator.processPaths(DefaultGenerator.java:688)
        at io.swagger.codegen.DefaultGenerator.generate(DefaultGenerator.java:376)
        at io.swagger.codegen.cmd.Generate.run(Generate.java:223)
        at io.swagger.codegen.SwaggerCodegen.main(SwaggerCodegen.java:36)
```

Am I doing something wrong in the definition of the reusable parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a typo in your spec:

```
- $ref: '#parameters/reusableParam'
```

should be

```
- $ref: '#/parameters/reusableParam'
```